# Connecting a database on computer in Android Studio

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I am currently working on a project in Android Studio. I had created a database full of information on my computer, and I wanted my program to connect to that database specifically.

However, it doesn't seem to work for me. For test purposes I created a test database to check if my code works. It looks something like this: (I have not bothered to put in the create statements for tables/other database related methods)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sample_database";

public SampleDBSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   ...
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   ...
}
}
```

Would appreciate any help on this. Whenever I looked it up I got answers to connect sqlite database on remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is but here is an example of a database helper class which will enable you to write data to SQL on the mobile app.

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Database.db";
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE  = "TABLE";
  
    public static final String COL1 = "ID",COL2 = "D2", COL3 = "D3";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // creating required tables
        String CREATED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "D1 TEXT, D2 TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATED_TABLE);
  
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean addData_Sensor_Board(String d1, String d2){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();//Enable the database to be written to
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();//Setup the data input note COL1 is for the ID
        contentValues.put(COL2,d1);//2
        contentValues.put(COL3,22);//3
     

        long result = db.insert(TABLE,null,contentValues);//Check to see if pass in has been successful and pass in the data on this line via the pass in of content values
        if(result == -1){//Returned false when inputting data to the database
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;//No error
        }
    }
    public Cursor showData(){//Used to locate the data inside the database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return data;
    }
    public void delete_table(){//Clears the entire database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String clearDB = "DELETE FROM "+ TABLE;
        db.execSQL(clearDB);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have a pre-existing database which I had made on my computer. My android studio project is also on the same computer. I just want to connect that database to the project. Because I was not able to do so, I created a testing database instead of connecting the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no easy way to do it, but Florina Muntenescu wrote [this great blogpost](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/packing-the-room-pre-populate-your-database-with-this-one-method-333ae190e680) about how you could load a pre-populated database into your app with [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

After you've successfully loaded your database you could then use Android Studio 4.1 to manipulate the database using the built-in [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#database-inspector) (must also update the Android Gradle Plugin to 4.1.0 or above).